# How to fix the 'OK' message from the get request on angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, angular-material

I'm new using angular and I'm trying to make some httpClient get requests from my asp.net core composed for two different models tournament and league.

After run the project at the first time and get the tournament response, all seems okay. But when I switch to another page (league) or go back to tournament, I got a 'OK' message from my request.

**First request after run the project:**
!  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xqSK.png

**Another request after the first one:**
!  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcDFX.png

I checked my backend code in C# and seems okay because the first request was okay then, I'm thinking that I'm messing up on the request or my code to populate the table.

**tournament.Service.ts -> request:**

```
getAll(): Observable<Tournament[]> {
    return this.http.get<Tournament[]>(`${this.baseUrl}/api/tournament/GetAll`);
}
```

**tournament.component.ts -> set the request to MatTableDataSource:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from'@angular/material';
import { TournamentService } from 'src/app/services/tournament.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-tournament',
templateUrl: './tournament.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./tournament.component.css']
})
export class TournamentComponent implements OnInit {

@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'started', 'ended'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>();

constructor(
    private tournamentService: TournamentService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.TournamentDataSource();
}

TournamentDataSource() {
    this.tournamentService.getAll()
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            console.log("data");
            console.log(data);
            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);                    
        },
        error => {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}
}
```

I googled some ways to fix it. I tried use pipe before the subscribe like:

```
this.tournamentService.getAll()
        .pipe(map(
            data => {
                console.log("AASDASDSAD");
                console.log(data);
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);

                return data;
            }
        )).subscribe();
```

However the result was the same. Am I making the get request correctly?

Comment: Where are you calling the `getAll` function in your component? It would be easier to help if you could provide the component code or at least what's relevant.

Comment: Share us the full code for `tournament.component.ts`.

Comment: I edited the post with the full tournament.component.ts.

Comment: Looks like your request fails. Show the headers tab please. I suppose you get a status code other than 200. Also I would recommend to change `console.log(errror)` to `console.error(error)` to be more explicit and see some details

Answer (score 1):

After long research, I found the answer. The point was that I got circular deserialization from my Tournament class in .net core using entity framework.

The solution was to use a DTO that fixed my problem.
In the end, the HTTP request was correct though.